# Upload photoshop-created PNG to Discord without changing colours

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, png

Here's an icon made with photoshop:

[image]

Looks fine when I open it in Preview or Safari.

When I upload it to discord, the colours change completely:

[image]

I'm assuming this is due to the fact that photoshop saved it with an embedded color profile? And Discord isn't rendering it with this colour profile?

E.g. I've noticed photoshop's RGB values are different than my system-wide rgb values:

[image: /Users/George/Downloads/Screen Shot 2018-01-21 at 12.40.57.png]

All I want to know is, how can I take that PNG (the first one) and make it so that when I upload it to discord it will still look the same?

Comment: Well what is your document profile set to? And do you actually have a calibrated monitor?

Comment: @joojaa of course, all monitors are calibrated? the monitor has nothing to do with this though

Comment: No, most monitors  are not calibrated abou 98% have never been calibrated or profiled. This calibration needs to be done on a monthly- weekly basis for it to be meaningfull.  Also without a calibrated monitor fighting about this is aboit as useful as a bike is for a fish. The error people on other monitors is grater than the error you see also i can not see the same error for the simple reason that your monitor is not calibrated. But you didnt answer the question.

Comment: @joojaa I don't know what a document profile is. Also, monitor calibration has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Off course it has, photoshop is trying to emulate some space on the space your OS tells the monitor is in. If your monitor is in sRGB which they frequently are not then setting profile to sRGB wont help. Anyway look into **Edit -> Color Settings**

Comment: @joojaa what color settings do I need to select so that when i save the png and upload it to discord the colours stay the same?

Comment: well usually sRGB but you need to have your monitor in sRGB space. Which is a bit problematic on wide gamut displays. Alternative is to embed the color space, which works on some browsers. Aslo set it to warn when opening documents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with a method that avoids photoshop because it seems every time I touch that everything breaks. My method is to take the graphic created with photoshop, and use it to punch a hole through a sample of the color that I want.

I opened that png, the one that was meant to be my icon, in Preview.app (not photoshop because photoshop was messing everything up) and then maximise contrast, made saturation as low as possible, and mess around with other settings, like maximising/minimising exposure, to make it completely black on a transparent background.

Then I cmd-A copied it all, drew a white rectangle, and pasted it down again. So now my original image is a completely black-on-white icon.

The color settings in Preview let you invert colours by moving the leftmost levels arrow to the right, and the rightmost to the left.

Now it should be white-on-black. Save that. This will be a mask.

[image]

Then I screenshotted the color I actually wanted. I used Preview's resize to resize that color to a 1000x1000px square (the size of my final image). Just a solid color. Screenshotting a solid block of color from the original png that you want to preserve the color of (first image of question) would have worked too.

[image]

Then I ran this command with imagemagick:

```
convert color.png mask.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite warningicon.png
```

It spat out exactly what I wanted, which was a png of the correct color that doesn't weirdly change colours when uploaded to discord.

[image]

Comment: It does not really answer the question as asked. it might do what you want.

Comment: @joojaa I think it does answer the question "all I want to know is, how can I take that PNG (the first one) and make it so that when I upload it to discord it will still look the same?"

Comment: Yes. Nobody else would have had a chance to answer this particular answer thus its invalid as the question was asked. Thus as answer its out of scope. Since its your question your free to edit them to match.

Comment: @joojaa this answer and the question do match. I don't understand what you mean "nobody else would have had a chance to answer this particular answer"—answers aren't meant to be answered. It's a totally, 100% valid answer to the question.

Comment: You need to tag it with something other then photoshop and say your willing to accept nonphotoshop answers. Though its just easier to configure your photohop. But then i can not revert the negative vote. Just saying,

Comment: @joojaa but the problem derives from photoshop, thus the photoshop tag. PhotoShop-configuration answers are acceptable, thus the photoshop tag. "Easier to configure your photoshop"—maybe for some, but I spent 6+ hours on this when I was trying to figure it out inside of photoshop and got nowhere, that's why I asked the question. If someone can tell me how to configure photoshop properly, I'll accept that answer obviously.

Comment: No, you need to indiocate your open to nonphotoshop answers otherwise its like asking about a javascript question on stackoverflow and coming up with a python answer. I told you to put the warnings on after configuring your working space. That would next time you open a document fix your issue. BUt again i can not remotely configure your computer.

Comment: @joojaa it's really not like that. If my stackoverflow question was "How do I filter a list of files by content?" and I'd been trying with windows batch (and thus it's tagged with batch) because I'm going to use this in a batch script, but someone posts a python script as an answer because it's nigh impossible in batch, the python answer is fine, and a good answer to the question. When it's impossible with one tool, use another, right? This answer answers the question as asked, I have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: No problem just explaining why your getting downvoted. Would you have accepted answrers showing how to do this with MS paint?

Comment: @joojaa yeah I would have

Comment: Then next time you ask indicate that in your question! Otherwise the answers will only include photoshop answers.

Comment: @joojaa I don't see where the opposite is implied in my question, or why my answer "does not really answer the question as asked." I think the question as asked, "how can I take that PNG and make it so that when I upload it to discord it will still look the same?" makes no restrictions on what technology you're allowed to use to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72093/discussion-between-joojaa-and-theonlygusti).